# Get video encoding or mime type from Video stream

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

I'm here to ask if there is some method for retrieving **media type** or **encoding** from **VideoView** in **Android**.

I tried this code:

```
    //Get the video media type
    try {
        ContentResolver cR = getContext().getContentResolver();
        String type = cR.getType(Uri.parse(url));
        Log.d("MyClass", type == null ? "???/???" : type);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("MyClass", e.getMessage());
    }
```

But does not work, always return **null**.
I need to distinguish two types of video stream visualization, **MJPEG** and VideoView supported type **(H.264/H.265, etc...)**.

I Won't use libVLC because is quite expansive and compilation is only compatible with Linux machine(I work on Windows);

I want to use VideoView because is light, simple and works like a charm.

I need a function that does this:

```
//Get Video Type
int type = getVideoType(url); 

//Load the stream
if(type == MJPEG) 
    loadMjpegOnView(url); 
else
    loadVideoView(url);
```

So with the URL, I need to distinguish MJPEG to another video format.
I Search on the web for a lot and I didn't find **anything** useful.

Comment: What is the value of `ipAddress`? What is the value of your proposed `url`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i edit the question, ipAddress == url

Comment: So, what is the value of the `url`? Or, at least, what is the scheme of the URL? `https`? `http`? `rtsp`? Something else?

Comment: Is a tested and correct url from an IP Camera.

Comment: That does not answer the question. What is the value of the url? Or, at least, what is the scheme of the URL? `https`? `http`? `rtsp`? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare every protocols you describe (https/http/rstp)

Comment: I have no control of witch protocol i use, but is 100% http/https/rtsp

Comment: If the scheme is `http` or `https`, you can perform an `HEAD` request and examine the `Content-type` header to determine what the server claims the MIME type is. I do not know if there is an equivalent for RTSP.

Comment: The only thing i know is that a videostream from a generic ip camera, for example url like this: rtsp://admin:pass@:ipAddress:port/Streaming/Channels/101/